# Overwrite default data type C++

Tags: c++

I have a program that was designed to run only on 32-bit systems, and I want to port it to 64bit.  I'm using FreeBSD 12.1 amd64 ... and long and int have different sizes.

I want to overwrite the default data type long to int.
Can I do something like `typedef long int;` or `using int = long;`?

Comment: I don't think that's legal. Anyway, if you care about the size of ints, you should use `int32_t` etc from `<cstdint>`.

Answer (score 2):

No, the behaviour on attempting to change a C++ keyword in undefined.

So, using `typedef`, `using`, and even `#define` are not solutions.

If you need integral types to be the same across platforms, then use the fixed width types `std::int32_t` etc.

Comment: In my opinion, this is best practice *anyway*, since you always know what size are your values, instead of depending on implementaion based `int` and `long`. (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do something like `typedef long int;` or `using int = long;?`

No. You cannot do that.

Safest way to port your program is to modify the source.